# How to make custom CSS snippets in Lemoon CMS

Tags: lemoon

Im just beginning with Lemoon CMS and updating multiple websites with new look.
I cant find any css files/fields to edit? 
Do i need to have ftp access or if this is done by admin login in Lemoon 4 CMS? I just cant find anything about it. 
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check folders: ~/css/ and ~/admin/theme? As far as I know all default .css files are in those folders.

Comment: should be comment instead .